# Get the value of a PowerShell function into a T-SQL declared variable for further processing

Tags: sql-server, powershell

My need is to get the **correct** size of the last backup of a database. For example, a file share's destination folder, say `\\<FSServer>\<Some_final_folder>\<ServerName>\<DatabaseName>\<DBName_etc.BAK>` where `FSServer` is the FQDN of the share file server where the backup of the database is retained, and `Some_final_folder` is the FQDN of the folder where the backup file would be stored. A specific example:

```
\\FileShare\DBBackups\Server1\DB1\DB1.BAK
```

When a customers asks what the size of the backup file is, I wish to be able to provide them with an accurate answer.

I run a query on msdb to get the details, but have found that this doesn't provide me with an accurate size. So I thought to look at the **actual** size of the backup file on the physical folder.

I used a simple PS script to get to the final destination folder, and get the ACTUAL size, and it DID provide me with the CORRECT value.

What I want now, is to get the result of my PS script's value into a T-SQL variable, that I can encapsulate as part of a snippet/function/procedure/?

How can I do this?

Comment: I suggest reducing your question down to something as simple as possible. You have written us an essay which makes it difficult to work out exactly what you want. I am fairly sure you can ask your actual question in about 2 sentences.

Comment: This site is primarily a software development q&a - please add any supporting code samples to illustrate the problematic behaviour as you’re much more likely to get a positive response that way - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Not saying you're wrong, but I've found the values in msdb with respect to backup size to be pretty reliable. What query are you using?

Comment: You likely have a compressed backup or VSS snapshot that just estimates backup file size. Please add exact queries you've used, and examples of the file sizes on disk and on the msdb table.

Comment: You can use xp_cmdshell to call the powershell script and then process the output, or use CLR to create a .NET function which does this. using xp_cmdshell have security downsides though. I fail to see why you need to get this data from the database though, unless your clients are performing raw queries. Surely your frontend can do this work for you

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?